# DJANGO - change a form value with request.POST?

Tags: django

so i have this code:

```
post = request.POST.copy()
post['relationshipId'] = theRelationship.id
theStory = StoryForm(post, request = request, initial {'relationshipId' : theRelationship.id})
```

initially, my code looked like this:

```
theStory = StoryForm(request.POST, request = request, initial {'relationshipId' : theRelationship.id})
```

which caused validation problems. The validator would complain that the relationshipId wasn't set. Why would this be?

EDIT: the first block of code works fine, and I am super-happy with it. The question pertains to the second block of code, which was initially what I had (and what i've just spend some time working on) which, to me, is acting "weird"

Comment: Where is `theRelationship.id` coming from?

Comment: the same form. Um, what happens is two objects are in the form. theRelationship is a django Form that has been constructed and saved. Then the code i pasted above runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet sets the `relationshipId` field dynamically, instead of taking it from the POST parameters supplied in the web request.

The second snippet will take that value directly from `request.POST`, so if your form submits an invalid value, or if no value is given, it will not validate.

The `initial` argument only applies to unbound forms (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#initial). You could leave it out here, because you are binding the form to `post` or `request.POST`.